# Trigger jQuery Validation Manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have i form i submit via jQuery's .submit(), unfortunately it does not trigger the validation plugin when i do it this way. If i place a submit button inside the form, it works perfectly.

Is there someway to trigger the plugin manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the jQuery [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method may be of use?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$("#myButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#myform").valid()){
        // the form is valid, do something
    } else{
        // the form is invalid
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
$('#someForm').valid();
```

which could also be done in the submit handler:

```
$('#someForm').submit(function() {
    if ($(this).valid()) {

    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: @Mikkel, the `.valid()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the form is valid or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
$(".selector").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form){
    form.submit();
   }
});
```

which autosubmits the form it is valid, so you .validate() instead of submit()